# How to sequentially read all the files in a directory and export the contents in Python?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a directory `/directory/some_directory/` and in that directory I have a set of files. Those files are named in the following format: `<letter>-<number>_<date>-<time>_<dataidentifier>.log`, for example:

```
ABC1-123_20162005-171738_somestring.log
DE-456_20162005-171738_somestring.log
ABC1-123_20162005-153416_somestring.log
FG-1098_20162005-171738_somestring.log
ABC1-123_20162005-031738_somestring.log
DE-456_20162005-171738_somestring.log
```

I would like to read those a subset of those files (for example, read only files named as `ABC1-123*.log`) and export all their contents to a single csv file (for example, `output.csv`), that is, a CSV file that will have all the data from the inidividual files collectively.

The code that I have written so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
file_directory=os.getcwd()

m_class="ABC1"
m_id="123"
device=m_class+"-"+m_id


for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(file_dir)):
    if str(device)+"*" in os.listdir(file_dir):
        print data_file
```

I don't know how to read a only a subset of filtered files and also how to export them to a common csv file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

just use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) lib to match file name pattern, and use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) lib to export.

Comment: Isn't regex an overkill for this question?

Comment: Or, even better, `glob`

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be better stated, based on your current code snipet, I'll assume that you want to:

1. Filter files in a directory based on glob pattern.
2. Concatenate their contents to a file named `output.csv`.

In python you can achieve (1.) by using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to list filenames.

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('foo*bar'):
    print filename
```

That would print all files starting with `foo` and ending with `bar` in
the current directory.

For (2.) you just read the file and write its content to your desired
output, using python's `open()` builtin function:

```
open('filename', 'r')
```

(Using `'r'` as the mode you are asking python to open the file for
"reading", using `'w'` you are asking python to open the file for
"writing".)

The final code would look like the following:

```
import glob
import sys

device = 'ABC1-123'
with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    for filename in glob.glob(device+'*'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as input:
            output.write(input.read())
```

Comment: That's great! if I want to make a float comparison `if [theinput] > [unixtimestamp:1464646738.0038605]` and then `output.write(input.read())` it into the csv file, how would I do this?

Comment: Please, update your question to include this particular requirement and any other that you need to achieve, and after you find an answer that satisfy you, accept it. Think that others may be interested in the same problem you are trying to solve, SO is not just about finding solutions to your needs, but it is about sharing, :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module to list the files.

```
import os

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

m_class = "ABC1"
m_id = "123"
device = m_class + "-" + m_id
file_extension = ".log"

# filter the files by their extension and the starting name
files = [x for x in files if x.startswith(device) and x.endswith(file_extension)]

f = open("output.csv", "a")
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as data_file:
        f.write(data_file.read())
    f.write(",\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a few adjustments, You were close

```
filesFromDir = os.listdir(os.getcwd())    

fileList = [file for file in filesFromDir if file.startswith(device)]

f = open("LogOutput.csv", "ab")
for file in fileList:
    #print "Processing", file
    with open(file, "rb") as log_file:
        txt = log_file.read()
        f.write(txt)
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```